# Android. Получить путь к файлу из URI. Получаю null

Tags: android, c#, xamarin, restsharp

Здравствуйте! 
Проблемка вроде стандартная но из примеров интернета  ничего хорошего не выходит
Задача: на мобильном приложении выбрать картинку из телефона и используя restSharp отправить на сервер. RestSharp просит путь к файлу, но по адресу который дает Uri "content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:18" не находит, стало быть наверно нужен прямой путь. Вот как его получить? Снизу привел типичный пример который у меня возвращает null, но сам Uri верен, так как в imageView картинка вполне вставляется. Может кто решал такую задачу передачу файла restSharp-ом.

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                var imageView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.editAvatarImageView);
                imageView.SetImageURI(data.Data);                
                selectedAvatar = data.Data;


                string path = null;

                string[] projection = new[] { Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data };
                using (ICursor cursor = ContentResolver.Query(data.Data, projection, null, null, null))
                {
                    if (cursor != null)
                    {
                        int columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data);
                        cursor.MoveToFirst();
                        path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: А если читать его через `getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)`, доступен?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот рабочий вариант, таки накопал за 3 дня в глубинах интернета

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
            {
                var imageView =             FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.editAvatarImageView);
                imageView.SetImageURI(data.Data);

               // selectedAvatar = data.Data;

                string doc_id = "";
                using (var c1 = ContentResolver.Query(data.Data, null, null, null, null))
                {
                    c1.MoveToFirst();
                    String document_id = c1.GetString(0);
                    doc_id = document_id.Substring(document_id.LastIndexOf(":") + 1);
                }

                string path = null;

                // The projection contains the columns we want to return in our query.
                string selection = Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id + " =? ";
                using (var cursor = ContentResolver.Query(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, null, selection, new string[] { doc_id }, null))
                {

                    var columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data);
                    cursor.MoveToFirst();
                    path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
                }

                imgPath = path;

            }
        }
```

Comment: на самом деле...это ведроид так работает :)). Т.е. зависит от версии ведроида, где то этот код рабочий,где то нет. 
Таких вот багов со стороны ведроида просто море..

Comment: Ну на Джили бине и лолипопе работает одинаково) дальше посмотрим. В принципе фреймворк может позволить решить какие-то мелочи.

Comment: значит этот код не рабочий для API 19 < . Можешь зачекать. Поэтому нужно вручную чекать уровень АПИ и соответственно добавлять код для более старой версии.